# visual c++ error C3867

Tags: c++

I've had a lot of problems with this code and i've fixed most of them but i dont know whats wrong here.

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: molar mass, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\heliz_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\molar mass\molar mass\source.cpp(54): error C3867: 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::close': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::close' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\heliz_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\molar mass\molar mass\source.cpp(55): error C3867: 'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::close': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::close' to create a pointer to member
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

That is the build output for visual studio 2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::basic_ofstream;//Thought it would help
using namespace std;
using std::basic_ifstream;//Thought it would help
using std::char_traits;//Thought it would help
/**
*   Author: Alex M.
*   Date: 3/12/2015
*   Desc: Calculates the molar
*           mass of compounds,
*           elements and 
*           substances. 
*/
void nor();
void tut();
void calc();
int i;
double m;

ifstream inFile;//Is this how to do if/ofstream?
ofstream outFile;
int main()
{
    char ele;
    bool a;
    a = true;
    if (i<1)
        tut();
    nor();
    while (a = true)
    {
        cout << "Enter your compound or type 'Help': "; 
        cin >> ele;
        calc();
        while (ele != '\n')//This part is unfinished but seems to work
        {

        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
void nor()//This is where i think the problem is
{
    inFile.open("runs.dat");
    outFile.open("runs.dat");
    inFile >> i;
    i++;
    outFile << i;
    inFile.close;
    outFile.close;
}
void tut()
{
    cout << "Enter your equation with each " << endl << "element seperated by a space." << endl;
    cout << "Example: HCl -> H Cl" << endl;
    cout << "If theres more than one ion of each " << endl << "element per equation, enter that " << endl << "ion as many time as it appears." << endl;
    cout << "Example: NaSO4 -> Na S O O O O" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I've already looked all over forums but no one else seems to be having my problem. 
I commented all over the code with where i *think* the problem is.

I'm very new to C so please don't judge my simplistic coding skills.

Comment: Typo: you need `inFile.close();` etc. but really you can remove that line and the following one. The destructor takes care of closing.

Comment: `while (a = true)` should probably be `while (a == true)`

Comment: @juanchopanza they're global variables

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yikes! I hadn't seen that. Alex, you *do* need to call `close()` here, but try to avoid global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the error message where it says:

```
source.cpp(54)
source.cpp(55)
```

that means those errors are on line 54 and 55 respectively. You'll find that those lines are:

```
inFile.close;
outFile.close;
```

You probably meant to call those functions:

```
inFile.close();
outFile.close();
```

It's an error to mention the name of a member function in that way if you are not calling the function (and function calls require parentheses).

However, a better design would be to make `inFile` and `outFile` be local objects inside the function where you are using them. Then the files will automatically be closed when those objects go out of scope.